# Adding two color maps using imagesc between two sets of curves with specified boundaries (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm trying to add two color gradients between two curves (in this example these are lines).

This is the code for what I've done so far

```
% the mesh
ns=1000;
t_vec = linspace(0,100,ns);
x_vec = linspace(-120,120,ns);
[N, X] = meshgrid(t_vec, x_vec);

% the curves
x1 = linspace(0,100,ns); x2 = linspace(10,110,ns);
y1 = linspace(-50,50,ns); y2 = linspace(-20,80,ns);

X1 = repmat(x1, [size(N, 1) 1]); X2 = repmat(x2, [size(N, 1) 1]);
Y1 = repmat(y1, [size(N, 1) 1]); Y2 = repmat(y2, [size(N, 1) 1]);

% the gradient function
cc = @(x,x2,x1) ...     
    1./(1+(exp(-x)./(exp(-x1)-exp(-x2))));
for i=1:ns
    CData1(:,i)=cc(x_vec,x2(i),x1(i));
    CData2(:,i)=cc(x_vec,y2(i),y1(i)); 
end
CData=CData1+CData2; % here I've added the two gradients

% mask
mask = true(size(N));
mask((X > Y2 | X < Y1) & (X > X2 | X < X1)) = false;

% finalized data
Z = NaN(size(N));
Z(mask) = CData(mask);
Z = normalize(Z, 1, 'range');


% draw a figure!
figure(1); clf;
ax = axes;                          % create some axes
sc = imagesc(ax, t_vec, x_vec, Z);  % plot the data
colormap('summer')
ax.YDir = 'normal' % set the YDir to normal again, imagesc reverses it by default;
hold on
plot(t_vec,x1,'r',t_vec,x2,'r',t_vec,y1,'k',t_vec,y2,'k')
ylim([-120 120]); xlim([0 100])
```

the result I get is

[image]

As you can see, the gradient stretches between the most lower line to the most upper line.

How can I separate between the two color data and present them in the same image (using imagesc) using a different colormap?

Comment: Clarification request - Can you elaborate on what you mean by "separate between the twp color data and present them in the same image using a different colormap?" - Do you want something like what you have right now but with different colormaps for each strip?

Comment: @RealReza, I want each section (between x2 and x1, and between y2 and y1) to have a different colormap, and that the gradient (given by the function) will be independent for both sections

Comment: I still dont understand what you want to visualize. Forget about colormaps etc. a minimal example of what you show is given with `imagesc(mask.*(CData1+CData2))`. You see ttwo stripes with some gradient at their edge and  NaN mask in between and around. The stripes have different color given by the CData1+CData2 info. Ok, what wrong in this visualization? how do you want it to be exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function called `comat` (see at the bottom of the answer) that I once made for something similar, I think you might find it useful in your case. Here's an example how to use it:

```
imagesc(t_vec, x_vec, comat(CData2.*mask,CData1.*mask)); 
colormap([summer(256).^2;flipud(bone(256).^0.5)]);   % and the two colormaps
set(gca,'Ydir','normal')
```

The result is:

[image]

I'm not sure this is what you meant, but you can see how the data of the thin stripe is only visualized using the `bone` b&w colormap, while the rest is with `summer`. I also "abused" the colormaps with a `^` factor for emphasizing the range of the gradient.

```
function z  = comat(z1,z2,DR)
% the function combines matrices z1 and z2 for the purpose of
% visualization with 2 different colormaps
% z1,z2 - matrices of the same size
% DR    - the dynamic range for visualization (default 256)

%example
%imagesc(comat(z1,z2)); colormap([jet(256);bone(256)]);

%defaults
if (nargin < 3);  DR=256;  end

%normalize to dynamic range,  integer values in the range  0 to DR
z1=double(uint32(DR*(z1-min(z1(:)))./(max(z1(:)-min(z1(:))))));
z2=double(uint32(DR*(z2-min(z2(:)))./(max(z2(:)-min(z2(:))))+DR+1));
thr=DR+2+10; %threshold where data is not important for z2, must be at least DR+2
z=z1.*(z2<thr)+z2.*(z2>thr);
end
```

Comment: it does not always work, especially if slopes of the curves are in an opposite direction

Comment: show me an example please where it doest work and how it shoud work. The "opposite" direction only means that you want to flip the order of the relevant colormap that you want to use. for example, `colormap([flipud(jet256)) ; bone(256)])` etc... The function I gave you is general, and separate the data given in the two arrays to different colormaps, no matter what data they have. I think you are probably not using it correctly.